# Using the same value twice in a prepared statement with PHP and MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-update

How do I initiate a user defined variable and use it twice in a single MySQL statement prepared on a PHP/MySQLi connection?

I have an application with a shopping cart where a user can add credit to their account and there are two fields that carry this value in the database: credit_balance and credit_available. I have separated the credit into two fields because a user can lay-by (a South African term for paying a deposit to secure an article for later purchase) an item and, while that is pending, the funds are set aside for the lay-by and cannot used elsewhere.

So, when a user adds credit to their account, I would like to update both fields and this is what I have come up with:

```
if($update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE user SET credit_balance = credit_balance + @new_credit, credit_available = credit_available + @new_credit WHERE user_id = ? AND @new_credit = ?") {
  $update->bind_param("ii", $user_id, $deposit);
  $update->execute();
  $update->close();
}
```

Instead of:

```
if($update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE user SET credit_balance = credit_balance + ?, credit_available = credit_available + ? WHERE user_id = ?") {
  $update->bind_param("iii", $deposit, $deposit, $user_id);
  $update->execute();
  $update->close();
}
```

What are the implications of doing it like the way I have and, is this a reliable solution? It is working on my local machine and I am worried about compatibility on a different machine/environment.

Comment: Although it may look neater, the second method is much clearer (IMHO).  Also not sure how your first statement works as you have `user_id = 1` in your SQL.

Comment: i think the first one will not work. mysql goes top to bottom and , so that ypu can only use user defined variables, that have been declared prior

Comment: @NigelRen I made a mistake there. The "1" is meant to be "?".

Anyway, I have checked the MySQL documentation and I cannot find any section stating whether or not the first method might not work on some versions of MySQL and this is where my concern is. I guess I will have to stick to the second method.

Comment: @nbk I tested the first method and it worked on my local machine and also on an  Amazon Linux AMI instance running MySQL 5.7.3.

Comment: no it doesn't https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=867c55a920d19f0fc25d57913a2bd467

Comment: @nbk Your example did not work because you left out the colon before the equal sign when assigning a value to new_credit. It should be new_credit := 99 in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would have been easy if mysqli supported named parameters - but unfortunately it doesn't. You might consider changing to PDO, which implements this feature.

From SQL perspective: user variables are tricky in MySQL, and planned for deprecation. I think the safest approach is to `select` the parameters in a subquery, then join it with the target table:

```
UPDATE user u
INNER JOIN (SELECT ? user_id, ? new_credit) p
    ON p.user_id = u.user_id
SET 
    u.credit_balance   = u.credit_balance   + p.new_credit, 
    u.credit_available = u.credit_available + p.new_credit
```

Comment: As to whether you can reuse the same named parameter with PDO or not depends on whether PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES is TRUE or not.

Comment: This looks cleaner. I will try this as soon as I get back to my workstation and advise.